# Correlation matrix correlations in R shown as "?" in the grid

Tags: r, matrix, na, pearson-correlation

I want to create a correlation matrix given the "data1.new"-dataset. 
I know that ´NA´ values are represented by question marks. I have removed the NA values by using the "complete.obs".

```r
data1.new<-data1[4:11]
summary(data1.new)
cor(data1.new, use = "complete.obs")
library(corrplot)
forcorrplot <- cor(data1.new)
corrplot(forcorrplot, method="number",shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

My results are as follows:

[image: Results]

Comment: Hi S.S, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide us with at least a sample of `data` with `dput(data)` or `dput(data[1:10,])` by editing your post with the output. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `cor` with `complete.obs` is not assigned to the object `forcorrplot`

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
mtcars[1:5, 2:5] <- NA
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method = 'number', shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

[image]

and now check with

```
M <- cor(mtcars, use = "complete.obs")
corrplot(M, method = 'number', shade.col=NA, tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

[image]